# How to use Bugzilla API in C#

Tags: web-services, api

I want to use the Bugzilla API to create a bug in C#.

Here is the link for the API:

```
http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/
```

I should use the WebService API, see:

```
http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html
```

But I don't know how to use it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tried [bugzproxy?](http://oss.dbc.dk/bugzproxy/)

Comment: Yes but there are no examples on the internet about creating a bug via bugzproxy + I don't have Bugzilla installed, I'm woking on the test webpage landfill.bugzilla.